# Automatically creat CSS based on html file ids and classes

Tags: html, css, editor

I was googleing this question but could not get any appropriate result.

Is there an option in the script editor to import html classes and ids automatically? So for the following html code example, the css structure below is automatically created:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
}
.container ul{
}
.container ul li{
}
.container ul li a{
}
```

Comment: using jquery you can do this. but can you be more specific about this you want to create this html on which triggered event?

Answer (score 0):

Some Editors like Dreamweaver create the CSS code automatically when you apply a certain formatting to it.

For example if you select red as font color in a paragraph it adds the respective CSS code.

Depending on how you configure your CSS styles it may be added to a separate file or in the same HTML as a `<style>` tag